# Correct bad query string from external link via htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, hyperlink

There are external links pointing to my site (that I have no control over) which contain bad query strings.  Here is an example:

```
http://www.example.com/page/&query=string
```

The above results in a 404 page on my site.  Because "http://www.example.com/page/" exists on my site, I want to use a .htaccess file to remove any bad query strings so the user can get to the correct content.

So I want this rewrite or redirect:

```
http://www.example.com/page/&query=string  -> http://www.example.com/page/
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: so you actually don't want to show query string or redirect to cleared string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do as you said issuing a 301 redirect to the requesting browser.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=string
RewriteRule ^/page/ /page/ [R=301]
```

However you just want to serve the right content you can avoid the 301 redirect with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=string
RewriteRule ^/page/ /page/ [PT,NS,E=QUERY_STRING:]
```

It will remove the QUERY_STRING entirely so be aware.

If you wanted to rewrite some different query strings but not all for /page/

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=badstring1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=badstring2 [OR]
RewriteRule ^/page/ /page/ [PT,NS]
```

All RewriteRules assume that you have the "RewriteEngine On" somewhere, it is possible likely that your host has this done.  It will also require the mod_rewrite module in Apache which I assume is in use based on the .htaccess request.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

That all said this seems very unnecessary as a page will ignore the arguments if it does not need them, unless of course this is being passed to a script in which case you should be able to handle this in the code, but perhaps you have a framework that is causing issues.

This is a great book on the subject:
[Pro Apache](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001FOPW8K)
See pages 277-299